# Application of Gauss law to find the field on surface of a metallic spherical shell

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, conductors

Consider a hollow metallic spherical shell given a charge Q. The entire charge must reside on the outer surface of the hollow sphere. Now consider a Gaussian surface on the outer surface of the sphere. By spatial symmetry the field at every point on the surface
is the same , let it be ‘E’.

The flux through the entire surface is $E.4\pi r^2$ Which is equal to $ charge  enclosed / epsilon$. Since charge enclosed is zero, this implies that the Field at every point is 0.

But that is certainly not the case as the field on the outer surface is nonzero, can someone please help me find the mistake in my application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so long as the charge lies inside the gaussian surface you can calculate the flux but not if it lies on or outside the surface.In your case what is meant by the potential at the surface is actually the potential just outside the sphere of charge and thus gauss law is applicable

Comment: Where exactly is your Gaussian surface?  Just outside or just inside the sphere? Pick one or the other, and Gauss' Law applies.   Right *on* the surface charge?  That makes no sense in the simplified classical E&M where charge is continuous and what amounts to infinite compressibility

Comment: What about the electrostatic pressure on the surface of the conductor ?